# "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'list' and 'int'" , for array random of number on arrDecode

Tags: python-3.x

i have function,

def calculatefitness(arrDecodeX1, arrDecodeX2):

```
calculate fitness = (4-((2.1)*pow(arrDecodeX1,2))+(pow(arrDecodeX1,4)/3))*(pow(arrDecodeX1,2)+(arrDecodeX1*arrDecodeX2))+(((-4+(4*pow(arrDecodeX2,2)))*pow(arrDecodeX2,2)))
return 1/(hasilfitness+0.01)

print("total fitness : ", calculatefitness)
```

but i get an error "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'list' and 'int'"

my formula :

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/weErq.png

Comment: What are `arrDecodeX1` and `arrDecodeX2`?

Comment: The error tells you the problem, you can't pass a list into the `pow` function. Use a numpy array, or operate on each value in the list instead

Answer (score 0):

pow() function takes numbers only
you cannot pass array on it

For example: pow(a, b) a & b must be numbers